# Postman caches a response from an API

Tags: postman

I have a request to call one API to retrieve a value  in postman. My request requires different headers. WHen i set different values to the headers and call the API i always get the same result form the API.

I am removing the headers to see if i get a different response from my API  but when i call the API again  it stills returns the same response. I checked the curl and the headers i removed are not even passed so maybe is the response the one that is cached and returned to me..

[image]

I have deleted cache files on my browser, restarted Postman, passed the header  Cache-Control:no-store , deleted all the headers but  the response is always the same from the API

Comment: There could be lots going on here, it's hard to tell from a cropped images of a single section of the app. Which version is this? What are the hidden Headers? If you go to the Request settings tab and disable the cookie jar, is that doing anything different?

Comment: I would actually just say that the token you've sent in your header is expired, as the message properly states it...